# Updating data/state between directives in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

this may be a silly question and I may not explain myself well but here goes... I have a form with the current HTML tags, please note the directives:

```
<input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" ng-model="user.plaintextPassword" equals="{{user.password2}}" required ng-trim="false" error-popover>
<label for="password1">Password 1</label>

<input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" ng-model="user.password2" equals="{{user.plaintextPassword}}" required ng-trim="false" error-popover >
<label for="password2">Password 2</label>
```

Now on both of these tags I have AngularJS directives. The `equals` directive watches both values of the passwords and should they match/not match it sets the validity of the model, like so:

```
   .directive('equals', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {
                if(!ngModel) {
                    return;    // do nothing if no ng-model
                }

                // watch own value and re-validate on change
                scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
                    validate();
                });

                // observe the other value and re-validate on change
                attrs.$observe('equals', function () {
                    validate();
                });

                var validate = function() {
                    // values
                    var val1 = ngModel.$viewValue;
                    var val2 = attrs.equals;

                    // set validity
                    ngModel.$setValidity('equals', val1 === val2);
                    //console.log(ngModel);
                };
            }
        }
```

Now I have another directive that produces a validation popup should the form item be invalid, this is fired on the keydown or focus of the form item (here is an edited version):

```
   .directive('errorPopover', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                // validate on keydown and focus in input field
                element.on('keydown focus', function() {
                    scope.$evalAsync(function() {

                        var popoverOptions = {
                            'placement': (attrs.errorPopover) ? attrs.errorPopover : 'left',
                            'trigger': 'manual',
                            'content': setValidationText(attrs, ngModel)
                        };

                        // raise the error etc...
                    });
                });


                // hide popover when user leaves input
                element.on('blur', function() {
                    // do stuff
                });

                var setValidationText = function(attrs, ngModel) {
                    var errorText = '';

                    // lots going on here... and then
                    if(attrs.equals && ngModel.$error.equals === false) {
                        // add to the error text
                    }

                    return errorText;
                };
            }
        };
```

Now this doesn't work as the `ngModel` is different and whilst the `equals` directive keeps the correct validity value the `errorPopover` directive doesn't. So the value may be false but in the `errorPopover` directive the `ngModel.$error.equals` always remains true. How do I update the `errorPopover` directive with the correct value determined by the `equals` directive?

**PLEASE NOTE: I'm after advice or a push in the right direction more than a code example... as I am unsure if this is about isolating scope or broadcasting, etc, etc...**

Comment: a demo in plunker would help. Hard to help troubleshoot without being able to use console

Comment: seems to me  `errorPopover` should only watch model validity, not be bound to element events.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making this far too complicated.  Directives are primarily for DOM manipulation.  In your equals directive you're simply doing data validation, so a controller function would be better.

You can eliminate your 'equals' custom directives and in place of it add in ng-change="validatePassword()" on both inputs (you may also want to call this function when the form is submitted if you include other validation logic such as password strength tests).  Then it's a simple matter of a comparison check in the function and if the two variables do not match, then display your popover.

Your popover also seems too complex.  I would try to keep the HTML in your HTML file, then just control the show/hide (or use ng-if) from your controller function.  I would move whatever relevant logic you have in popover either to the validation function, or perhaps in a separate function if it's reusable across different types of validations.  So you end up simply showing/hiding a section of the HTML if the validation function is true or false.  It's an easy pattern to follow and keeps your HTML together.

Hope this sends you in a simpler direction.